About inequality of moment
Suppose $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is expectation value of some real random variable X. It is known that for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[{X}])^2]\leq\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[{X}]+a)^2]$. Can we generalize this inequality to higher order. That is, can we show $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[{X}])^{2p}]\leq\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[{X}]+a)^{2p}]$ like inequality?
[Added]
Thaks for a lot counter examples.

No.
Let's $2p=4$ and $\mathbb{E}X=0$.
Then we want
$$
0 \le 4a\mathbb{E}X^3 + 6a^2\mathbb{E}X^2 + a^4.
$$
Clearly, we can take a negative $a$ and big positive $\mathbb{E}X^3$, that the right hand side will be negative.

I doubt it is true if the distribution of $X$ is asymmetric.
One counter-example will be enough:

suppose $\mathbb P(X=0)=\frac14$ and $\mathbb P(X=4)=\frac34$ so $\mathbb E[X]=3$
consider $a=1$ and $p=2$ so $2p=4$
then $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[{X}])^{2p}] = \frac14 (0-3)^4 + \frac34 (4-3)^4=21$
while $\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[{X}]+a)^{2p}] = \frac14 (0-3+1)^4 + \frac34 (4-3+1)^4=16$
but $21 > 16$.


In a different direction, taking $p=2$ for example, and assuming $\Bbb E[X^4]<\infty$, the function
$$
f(b):=\Bbb E[(X-b)^4]
$$
is strictly convex and tends to $+\infty$ as $b\to\pm\infty$, so $f$ has a unique minimizer $b_0$. By calculus, $b$ solves the cubic
$$
b^3-3\mu_1 b^2+3\mu_2b-\mu_3=0,
$$
where $\mu_k:=\Bbb E[X^k]$. Standardizing $X$, we can assume that $\mu_1=0$ and $\mu_2=1$. The equation for $b$ becomes
$$
b^3+3b-\mu_3=0,
$$
so the minimizer depends only on the skewness of the distribution of $X$.
